# Do I need a model or a layer between controller and WCF in .net MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, design-patterns, model

I have a web application (using .Net MVC) that exposes some functionality built using a WCF service. In this case my controller action calls WCF service methods directly to work with data.

- Do I need a model at all in this case?
- Do I need any extra layer between my controller action and WCF?
- If *yes*, what would be the reasons?

Current scenario:
**[.Net MVC] <-> [WCF] <-> DB**

Here is what my method looks like

```
public JsonResult GetLastJob()
{
    try
    {
        DistributionJob job = jobDataServiceClient.GetLatestJob();

        return Json( new
            {
                success = true,
                job = job
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends - does your view need more information that in sound in the object returned from the WCF service?

Personally I don't like duplicating objects. If I have a POCO object that is filled by EF, I'd rather use it throughout the entire system. Most of the times, however, the view model requires additional information, so I just put the POCO as a field in the view model.

So, if your WCF service has a `MyObject GetObject()` method, I usually end up creating the following view model:

```
class MyViewModel
{
    public MyObject MyObject { get; set; }
    ... additional data required by the view ...
}
```

Comment: That is a good option. Right now I just send the data as JSON. I have added my controller method definition in the question. If you have any suggestions based on that.

Comment: You don't have a view, so you definitely don't need a view-model.

Comment: Yes. And I don't need a Model or any layer between my controller and WCF either right? Sorry that's departing from the original question, I hope that's OK.

Comment: Updated my question. I realized that I wanted to ask a general question about adding a layer, not just model.